# MongoDB Text search - search contain in string

Tags: mongodb

Let say I have a user like bellow

```
[
{
username : "madhusudhanarao.ch"
}
]
```

I create index text for username field, but I can't use text search to find this user

```
db.collection.find({$text : {$search : "madhus" }})
```

I have to search the full text like `madhusudhanarao` or `ch`

I know I can use regex to search but all my code are use $text $search. I can't fix all of them.

Comment: As far as I know, the $text operator does not do partial/substring searches. You would have to use regex like you mentioned or perhaps Atlas Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we normally use in sql, the "%like", We use [regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for the same purpose on MongoDB

Better read documentation, and you can find Option which you can implement on your search.

**db.colection.find({username: {$regex : text }})**

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but all my code uses $text search, and I can't fix it for each function